# User Session Management in RoR API for Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, session

I am building an API in RoR to be used by an android app. I have looked at various other similar questions on SO but found nothing which fits my exact use case. I need to identify a logged in user and respond to the request accordingly. This goes just beyond getting the user id to user categories, implicit preferences (different from settings) to give the user a more personalized experience.

In a web app this is done through a session cookie using which I can essentially call the following methods:

```
current_user.id         # Gets user's id
current_user.category   # Gets user's category
current_user.auth_level #Gets user's permission level
```

To do this, in the webapp I have the following setup:

In login action:

```
...
      @user_session = session_setter(email, password)
... 
      def session_setter(email,password)
                   @session = UserSession.new(:email => email, :password => password)
                   @session.save
      end
```

UserSession.rb

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
logout_on_timeout true
last_request_at_threshold 100
  skip_callback :persist, :persist_by_cookie
  skip_callback :after_save, :save_cookie
  skip_callback :after_destroy, :destroy_cookie

end
```

session_store.rb (configured for memcached)

```
require 'action_dispatch/middleware/session/dalli_store'
App::Application.config.session_store  :dalli_store, :memcache_server => ['127.0.0.1:11211'], :key => '_session'
```

This setup allows me to access `current_user` object once the user is logged in and access all columns in the table `users`.

For android, this is what I have figured out:

Create an `api_key` for each user who creates an account. This could have an expiry date. Maintain and store this key in the `users` table. The `api_key` is passed on to the app on the first request where it is stored in something like `sharedPreferences`. Every request should carry the a`pi_key` to the server. Put filters on actions which require the user to be logged in, to check if the key is present or not.

Now, here is my question: In this setup I would need to retrieve the users record from the table (or store it in the memcached with the `api_key` as  a key value pair) on every request through the filter.Is there a way to use something like `current_user` with the api?

In short I want to to replicate the same strategy for maintaining logged in users for the api as I have for the web app.

Answer (score 1):

API is supposed to be unaware of your web-app contexts.
API is the classical stateless HTTP.

You ask it a question, it gives you answers. Albeit, from your web app's state and data, but it has no concern with what goes on at that end.

An API cannot, or rather, should not be coupled with the user logged in/ logged out state.

It is your webapp's responsibility to query the API with as much information it needs to reflect the logged in state.

Eg.,
If your API has a method `get_recommendations`,

- it should ideally take in multiple args, to be able to handle all cases
- logged out users, will make the query, wrt the page being viewed. As in, a matrix movie scene being viewed, should give other matrix scenes as reco's
- logged in users, will make the query, wrt other aspects. As in, how many action videos has been viewed by this user, can be passed in as an arg.

The API endpoint should have the ability to handle both these scenarios seamlessly.
Make other calls to other methods if need be, to find out the current user's (identified by a user id key passed in) details.

So, from a design perspective, you should not pass in anything other than the fact that this request is for a signed in user with id = X.

Let your API handle everything else.

API is nothing but a special function/method.

Methods can do pretty much anything, as long as they remain true to their description / signature.

Comment: Got it. I need to do the course correction for it to handle both situations. However, I am not using the 'id = X' scenario. Instead of user's id, a unique api_key (generated for each user) will be passed to identify which user's app instance is requesting the API. Based on this unique key, I need to be able to access an object similar to current_user. My question is really about how to obtain/generate the correct current_user object implicitly in the case of an API as it is done in the case of a generic Web App.

Comment: each api key should be mapped to a user. table `api_keys` should have a `user_id` column, based on what you describe. that `user_id` represents the user who requested. Let the API query your db to find out which user made that request. and call a magic method on that user object to get his "state". Makes sense?